# How many ways are there to arrange $12$ (distinct) people in a row so that Dr. Tucker is $3$ positions away from Dr. Stanley?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to arrange $12$ (distinct) people in a row so that Dr. Tucker is $3$ positions away from Dr. Stanley (i.e., $2$ people are in between Dr. Tucker and Dr. Stanley), e.g., _ _ _ _ T _ _ S _ _ _ _ ?

There are $10$ other people besides Dr. Tucker and Dr. Stanley. Their spots would be determined by $10!$. I am not sure how to incorporate the two spaces in between Dr. Tucker and Dr. Stanley.

Comment: Do you need Tucker to be on the left of Stanley ?

Comment: No they can be anywhere just need 2 spaces in between them.

Answer (score 7):

Dr. Stanley can be either $3$ positions before or behind Dr. Tucker. Either way, choose $2$ out of $10$ people to be between them (with order) and then consider the entire block of $4$ as one "person" to permute with the remaining $8$, yielding $2\cdot10\cdot9\cdot9!=65318400$ different arrangements.

Answer (score 7):

Consider first all possible arrangements of Dr. Tucker and Dr. Stanley having 2 spaces between them without worrying about the other people. First take Dr.Tucker always being to the left of Dr. Stanley. So T_ _ S _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ,is one such way and  _ T _ _ S _ _ _ _ _ _ _  is another etc. There are $9$ such ways. There are another $9$ such ways for Dr. Stanley to be on the left. In all these cases there are $10!$ ways for the other people to be arranged as you say. Thus in total there are $(9+9)\cdot 10!=2\cdot 9\cdot10!$ ways of ordering the line.